# CDATA section not being ignored by the parser

Tags: xml, cdata, .net-1.1

I'm reading some XML files containing CDATA sections. Now, the problem is that the XML parser (in NET 1.1) is giving me the following error: [XmlException: There is an invalid character in the given encoding. Line 12, position 6.]
The error is inside a CDATA section. More specifically, the character in question is an Š letter (but there are tons of other diacritics as well). I thought CDATA sections are completely ignored by the parser. Any ideas?

The relevant code is
<![CDATA[**some text here** ]]>

Comment: Have you correctly specified the encoding?

Comment: The encoding for the XML file is UTF-8. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, do you load your file with the correct encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I verify that?

Comment: Can you share the XML deserialization part of your code.

Comment: The code fails on the Load method                              XmlDocument xmlDoc = newXmlDocument();   
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("Docs.xml"));

Comment: Solved! I removed the UTF-8 encoding from the XML and replaced every instance of an illegal character with an appropriate escape sequence.

Comment: Could you try with this: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Docs.xml"), Encoding.UTF8));

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I don't get any errors but the special characters are not displayed at all. While I now have a working solution, it's not very elegant so possibly some of you out there could  come up with something that I'd use instead. Thanks

Comment: CDATA sections are not ignored by the parser. They are just parsed as text even if it would look like markup.

Comment: Yes, thank you. BTW, It was a stupid mistake on my part. I used Notepad to edit XML files but didn't save them as UTF-8 (or Unicode). Notepad, by default, saves files as ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in CDATA section is of the format of ${a_b:pp} it is throwing error. It is coming as a variable whose value is not defined in the Logic. It will throw parsing exception. What you can do is to give space between $ and other text.